# OpenCv3.3 installation error - undefined reference to

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to install OpenCv3.3 and still getting same error.

*//usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `g_drive_is_removable'*

*//usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri_async'*

*//usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri_finish'*

I installed all dependencies and followed this tutorial:
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Does anyone know the solution, or can show me the way?

Comment: Link the right library.

Answer (score 0):

undefined reference to "somerhing " it means that these so's can not find the SO's where these functions are defined.